# Creating a way to report messages

Tags: vb.net

I am curious about relaying messages from one app on one machine to another machine.  I have a shared network storage readily available to me.  My thought is that I want to run an app on a single machine that runs intranet uploads.  I cannot control anything about the domain or the shared network storage other than creating files/folders.

I want this app on its own machine to be able to report somehow to a completely different application installed on completely different user machines (so in case of errors lets say, users could intervene) and at some point, across platforms (vb.net/Access/etc).

The first thing that hit me was to stream write the upload app's status to a text file, and then have a timer on my users end app that monitors the file that the upload app writes to.

However, before implementing, I am wondering if I am reinventing the wheel, and theres a better way to do this.  I am seeking simple solutions, and eventually I would like to integrate this into VBA/Access.  What does SO think fits the bill? What is the downside to streaming a "log"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reinventing the wheel.  This is [Message Queuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue).  There are many existing solutions to do this, including MSMQ (built into Windows) and RabbitMQ.  There are also cloud based services like Azure AppFabric and Amazon Simple Queue Service.

Comment: To use this on a network/server, I would need access to that server to enable queueing correct? Marked as answered, answers my core question.